# Implement Template10 Controls will result in an unhandled XAML exception

Tags: exception, uwp, template10, unhandled

I have some problems to implement Template10 controls in my UWP project.

When I create a PageHeader control into my MainPage.XAML, I can see the control, edit the control and run the application. But unfortunately the application will break until the components initialize.

There´s no error description.

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
```

## endif

```
    }
```

Visual studio will highlight this line.

What am I doing wrong ?
When I run the Template10 Hamburger template, everything seems to be working fine.

I hope you can help me to understand how template10 is working. 
I´ve seen your MVA contents but for me it wasn´t clear how to use template10 in existing projects.

Answer (score 2):

don't forget with this control it sort of needs other things to function correctly.  1 key item is a Frame from which is created at start of the application based on the NavigationServiceFactory if you reference the samples you will see what I am referring to.  To drop it in an existing app and expect to run without some modifications, you should expect errors.

I would suggest referencing samples and other things associated.  the nuget package can be install to any new project or existing with the right configurations set.  theoretically you could set the Frame = {x:null} it should work but I haven't done it or needed to.  Or don't set it at all, it's part of the back navigation tracking that the control watches for.

if you hover over the "e"  in the method handler inside the ( ), you can look at the errors... e = exception :P, you might have to dig alittle.

Comment: Thank you for your quick respone. do you have some sort of samples, tutorials of how to getting started with template10? I wish to learn more about this genius framework but my programming skills are kinda restricted. I am quite new to UWP but I am starting to understand how UWP works. If I could get some learning material, I think I could deal with it. My idea is to create an app which stores passwords and license keys. So I have to create a loginscreen which navigates me to the Mainpage. My application was quite good but I´ve got some brutal memory leaks with the NavigationManager.

Comment: http://www.github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/tree/master/Samples samples are pretty basic, but they get the point across

Comment: as for Login, I use IsFullScreen = true, and that allows me to navigate at startup to a LoginPage, process login and then set IsFullScreen = false, which will bring the navigation buttons back into view.  SettingsService gets used a lot and is very helpful for this

Comment: Thank you. I want to check this samples out, first.

Comment: In the meantime I´ve found a good blog where Template10 is explained. I wanted to share this little blog to help other people like me.  http://blog.qmatteoq.com/template10-a-new-template-to-create-universal-windows-apps-the-basics/